# Cyclic Pattern creation in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I create cyclic pattern in excel like,

[image]

Kindly help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, this is more like a community workshop than a coding service or tutorial portal, as you need to be specific about the problems you're facing, show your attempts at it, and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), in order to reduce the likelihood of your question being closed by moderators. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Investigate the ROW(), COL(), INDIRECT(), and ADDRESS() functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your initial pattern in Row 1 starting in A1.

In A2 put:

```
=IF(COLUMN()=5,$A1,B1)
```

copy over 5 columns and down as far as you wish.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In **A2** enter:

```
=B1
```

and copy across to **D2**; in **E2** enter:

```
=A1
```

then copy **A2** through **E2** downwards as far as you need.

[image]